# zio-grpc with Scala 3 (2nd try)

Tags: scala, scalapb

Does anyone have a bare-bones zio-grpc server, with codegen in the project also, working with Scala 3?

I started with the HelloWorld project from their repo and attempted to get it to build with scalaVersion := "3.1.0"

Here is the relevant section in plugins.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.thesamet.scalapb.zio-grpc" % "zio-grpc-codegen_2.13" % zioGrpcVersion,
  "com.thesamet.scalapb" % "compilerplugin_2.13" % "0.11.1"
)

excludeDependencies ++= Seq(
  ExclusionRule("org.scala-lang.modules", "scala-collection-compat_2.12"),
  ExclusionRule("com.thesamet.scalapb", "protoc-bridge_2.12")
)
```

and in build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.grpc" % "grpc-netty" % grpcVersion,
  "com.thesamet.scalapb" % "scalapb-runtime-grpc_2.13" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion
)

excludeDependencies ++= Seq(
  ExclusionRule("org.scala-lang.modules", "scala-collection-compat_2.12"),
  ExclusionRule("com.thesamet.scalapb", "protoc-bridge_2.12")
)
```

Since Scala 3 can use 2.13 libraries, that's what I'm doing. (Of the three zio-grpc-related libs, one, zio-grpc-codegen, does not have a Scala 3 version, so 2.13 must be used at least for that one.)

I get this error from sbt with the versions as above:

*java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.package$.Seq()Lscala/collection/immutable/Seq$;
at protocbridge.gens$.java(gens.scala:17)
at protocbridge.gens$.(gens.scala:11)*

If I remove either of the scala-collection-compat exclusions, we get

*[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/xxx/dev/zio-grpc/examples/helloworld/project/"), "helloworld-build"):
[error]    com.thesamet.scalapb:protoc-bridge _2.12, _2.13
[error]    com.thesamet.scalapb:compilerplugin _3, _2.13*

In short, I cannot find any permutation of Scala 2.13/3 versions of zio-grpc-codegen, compilerplugin_3, and scalapb-runtime-grpc that will not give some sbt conflicting cross-version suffix error.

Comment: Did you try to remove exclusions in `plugins.sbt` and use automatic Scala version? `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.thesamet.scalapb.zio-grpc" %% "zio-grpc-codegen" % zioGrpcVersion,
  "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "compilerplugin" % "0.11.1"
)`. What does it give you?

Comment: This won't work because one of the three libs (codegen) doesn't have a Scala 3 version. At the least one must use 2.13 for that. 

Exclusions were added as necessary only.

I tried pretty much every combination. The NoSuchMethodError from protocbridge is the "best" result I got as at least sbt doesn't die from cross-version collisions.

Comment: But did you try? Which error did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: this is not possible yet as some of the code you are using rely on macros and is not yet published for Scala3.

---

SBT plugins runs with Scala 2.12 no matter which Scala version is used in your project, thus you don't have to try to use plugins with `_2.13` or `_3` suffix, just use the regular syntax that will actually pick `_2.12` artifacts.

That is, in *plugins.sbt*:

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.thesamet.scalapb.zio-grpc" %% "zio-grpc-codegen" % zioGrpcVersion,
  "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "compilerplugin" % "0.11.8"
)
```

(No need for any exclusion).

You can confirm this by looking at sbt logs and you should see that it downloads plugins for version 2.12 of Scala:

```
...
https://somerepository.com/com/thesamet/scalapb/zio-grpc/zio-grpc-codegen_2.12/0.5.1/zio-grpc-codegen_2.12-0.5.1.pom
https://somerepository.com/com/thesamet/scalapb/compilerplugin_2.12/0.11.8/compilerplugin_2.12-0.11.8.pom
...
```

---

Once you do that, you'll get an error as following dependencies do not exist:

- `com.thesamet.scalapb:scalapb-runtime_3:0.11.1`
- `com.thesamet.scalapb:scalapb-runtime-grpc_3:0.11.1`
- `com.thesamet.scalapb.zio-grpc:zio-grpc-core_3:0.5.0`

For the 1st and 2nd, you just have to update the `compilerplugin` version to `0.11.8` as I did already above (the `compilerplugin` version is used for the main dependency `scalapb-runtime-grpc`).

For the 3rd, unfortunately it's not published yet for Scala 3. One attempt is to force the `_2.13` version for this one with something like that in the *build.sbt*:

```scala
libraryDependencies += ("com.thesamet.scalapb.zio-grpc" %% "zio-grpc-core" % "0.5.1") cross CrossVersion.for3Use2_13

excludeDependencies += "com.thesamet.scalapb.zio-grpc" % "zio-grpc-core_3"
```

But this doesn't compile with some errors related to macros, and that is something that is not compatible between Scala 2.13 and 3. **You cannot workaround that.**

---

Remember you can check available versions of a lib for a Scala version on Maven central:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thesamet.scalapb/compilerplugin
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thesamet.scalapb.zio-grpc/zio-grpc-core

Comment: We'd concluded the best route is to gen code separately, keeping that part (including the SBT plugin) out of the project. 

A Scala 3 server can be run with that code with no issues.

Thanks for this great, detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't released zio-grpc for Scala 3 as some tests related to `Has` were failing and were tricky to fix. At the same ZIO 2 is coming out and deprecated `Has`. There's a version of zio-grpc with ZIO 2 and Scala 3 support coming soon.